# TravisCI/Docker: parameterized start of docker containers with matrix feature

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I have a software that should be tested against a serious of WebDAV backends that are available as Docker containers. The lame approach is to start all containers within the before_install section like

```
before_install:
- docker run image1
- docker run image2
- ...
```

This does not make much sense and wastes system resource since I only need to have only on particular docker container running as part of test run.

My test configuration uses a matrix...it is possible to configure the docker image to be run using an environment variable as part of the matrix specs?
This boils down to two questions:

- can I use environment variables inside steps of the before_install section
- is the 'matrix' evaluated before the before_install section in order to make
  use of environment variables defined inside the matrix

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is yes.

I have been able to build indepentant dockerfiles using the matrix configuration. A sample dockerfile might look like

```
sudo: required

services:
    - docker

env:
    - DOCKERFILE=dockerfile-1
    - DOCKERFILE=dockerfile-2

before_install:
    - docker build -f $DOCKERFILE .
```

In this case there would be two independant  runs each building a separate image. You could also use a `docker pull` command if your images are on the docker hub.